# Typo3 Fluid ViewHelper for random page

Tags: fluid, typo3-flow, viewhelper

I am making my first site with typo3 and I need to place a boxes with random pages on my first page.

I made an frontend extension and I have a ViewHelper in it wich displays a box with HelloWorld text in it.

**My question is** how to get the information about pages, to get random page and it's content?

Answer (score 0):

Use cobject viewhelper and use Typoscript (hint the content element, google for it).